# Where do I put the .env file in a SvelteKit static app?

Tags: environment-variables, sveltekit

I have a statically generated SvelteKit app, which needs a Cloudflare Turnstile site key. This can be public (I'm aware you can't have private environment variables in a static site), but instead of hardcoding it at build time (I'm currently using a testing key), I wanted to put it in a `.env` file. It works in browser, even when I preview the built site, but as I am using a testing key, the Turnstile authentication can't actually take place. I have checked the SvelteKit docs and I can't find anything about it (for static sites).

Basically, I am asking where to put the `.env` file, and will it even work? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site is static, there is nothing to load an `.env` file at run time.

You can only use public and static variables from [`$env/static/public`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private). The "static" means that they are inserted into the code at build time and "public" means that they can be exposed in the client code (the only code a fully static application has). Such variables have to be prefixed with `PUBLIC_`.

If the key is not meant to be exposed to clients then having a fully static application is just not an option.

Comment: It's fine for the key to be exposed to the client; as I said in my original question. My stupid brain forgot that the project gets built on the actual machine it's hosted on, and that I'd write the .env variable there. Thanks.